# Saving HTML5 Location Info in File

Tags: php, html, file, location, geo

im trying to do the following with my current script:

- Saving Google Geo Location Informations in File, when the Visitor clicks "Accept Detection of my location"
- Output Google Maps URL with the Information

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #tripmeter {
        border: 0px double black;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px 0;
      }
      
      p {
        color: #222;
        font: 14px Arial;
      }
      
      span {
        color: #00C;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="tripmeter">
      <p>
        Starting Location (lat, lon):<br/>
        <span id="startLat">???</span>&deg;, <span id="startLon">???</span>&deg;
      </p>
      <p>
        Current Location (lat, lon):<br/>
        <span id="currentLat">???</span>&deg;, <span id="currentLon">???</span>&deg;
      </p>
      <p>
        Distance from starting location:<br/>
        <span id="distance">0</span> km
      </p>
    </div>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var startPos;
      
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            startPos = position;
            document.getElementById("startLat").innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("startLon").innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;
          }, function(error) {
            alert("Error occurred. Error code: " + error.code);
            // error.code can be:
            //   0: unknown error
            //   1: permission denied
            //   2: position unavailable (error response from locaton provider)
            //   3: timed out
          });
      
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
            document.getElementById("currentLat").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById("currentLon").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
            document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML =
              calculateDistance(startPos.coords.latitude, startPos.coords.longitude,
                                position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
          });
        }
      };
      
      // Reused code - copyright Moveable Type Scripts - retrieved May 4, 2010.
      // http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
      // Under Creative Commons License http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
      function calculateDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var R = 6371; // km
        var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
        var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
        var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) *
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
        var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        var d = R * c;
        return d;
      }
      Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
        return this * Math.PI / 180;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

    <meta charset="utf-8"/> 
    
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <div id="pos" style="width:800px; height:600px;">
        Detection Location..
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function initialize(coords) {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude, coords.longitude);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("pos"), myOptions);
            
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng, 
                map: map, 
                title: "You"
            }); 
        }
  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
            initialize(position.coords);
        }, function(){
            document.getElementById('pos').innerHTML = 'Failed to detect Location.';
        });
    </script>

<?php
$dns = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$rand2 = time();
$port= htmlspecialchars(
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT']);
$browser= htmlspecialchars(
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$ausgabe="• I WANT TO SAVE THE GOOGLE MAPS URL WITH THE DETECTED LOCATION •";
$datum=date("d.m.Y, H:i:s");
$array = file("location.log"); // Datei in ein Array einlesen
array_unshift($array, "".$datum." ".$ausgabe."\n");
$string = implode("", $array);
file_put_contents("location.log", $string);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone has a good idea? :)

Comment: Do we have any good idea for what? Are you having problems with it? Are you trying to improve the code? Please be a little more specific with what you need :)

Comment: The code looks like it was put together from 2 different sources. In any case, you'll have to send the coordinates to the server via AJAX, which means a separate script to handle the saving of the coordinates

Comment: im currently unable to "save" users location in file. i want to do it, but i dont know how, cause im a beginner in this. could you give me a example for my script with AJAX @itd? yes its 2 scripts combined together. (one for LAT LON TEXT, and one for showing on the map).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the longitude and latitude into a file (please check the Google API terms of usage if you are even allowed to do that), you have to get the coordinates first, then send them to your server via AJAX.

The below examples are not "copy/paste" material, since I didn't try them out. Use them as a general guideline.

First, you need to create a script, that will get the coordinates:

```
<html>
<head>    
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="pos" style="width:800px; height:600px;">
        Detection Location..
    </div>

    <script>
    $(function(){
            function initialize(coords) {
                $.ajax({
                   url: 'saveLocation.php',
                   data: {
                        longitude:coords.longitude,
                        latitude:coords.latitude
                        },
                   error: function() {
                      $('#pos').html("Could not save location");
                   },
                   success: function(data) {
                      $('#pos').html("Location saved successfully");
                   },
                   type: 'POST'
                });
            }

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){ 
                initialize(position.coords);
            }, function(){
                $('#pos').html('Failed to detect Location.');
            });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

On your server, you need a PHP script ""saveLocation.php":

```
<?php
$ausgabe=$_POST['longitude'].":".$_POST['latitude'];
$datum=date("d.m.Y, H:i:s");
$array = file("location.log"); // Datei in ein Array einlesen
array_unshift($array, "".$datum." ".$ausgabe."\n");
$string = implode("", $array);
file_put_contents("location.log", $string);

echo json_encode(array("success"=>"true"));
?>
```

I used jQuery to simplify some of the regular stuff, like sending data via AJAX or changing the inner HTML of an element.

Again, this code is not in working condition. It will not work if you just copy/paste it